# Rewrite bundle product options in admin

Tags: magento-1.8, product, overrides, bundled-product, attribute-options

I want to rewrite bundle options, i.e getProduct()  in my project. This is my code:

```
            <bundle>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select>Dima_Jumagaliev_Block_Admin_Product_Bundle_Select</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select>
                <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi>Dima_Jumagaliev_Block_Admin_Product_Bundle_Multi</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi>
                <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio>Dima_Jumagaliev_Block_Admin_Product_Bundle_Radio</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio>
                <catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox>Dima_Jumagaliev_Block_Admin_Product_Bundle_Checkbox</catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox>
            </rewrite>
        </bundle>
```

and php file:

```
class Dima_Jumagaliev_Block_Admin_Product_Bundle_Checkbox extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Composite_Fieldset_Options_Type_Checkbox {

public function getProduct()
{
    if (!$this->hasData('product')) {
        if(!is_null(Mage::registry('current_product'))) {
            $this->setData('product', Mage::registry('current_product'));
        } else {
            $productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('productId');
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
            $assotiatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
            $this->setData('product', $assotiatedProducts[0]);
        }
    }
    return $this->getData('product');
}
```

but still it doesn't work. Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: without seeing more of your module's configuration I would not be able to tell what is not setup properly. The code you do supply appears correct. Do you have caching turned off? How about logging enabled, is there any messages appearing in var/log/*.log?

Comment: Thank you. I fixed this bug.  
 $block->addRenderer('select','dima_jumagaliev/admin_product_bundle_select');